# Script to search my Google Sheets for a partial text match in a cell and if it contains a match then clear or delete entire cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I thought this would be more simple and easy to find online, but I'm having a difficult time so I'll try here first.  I'm Looking for a script to search my Google Sheets for a partial text match in a cell and if it contains a partial match then clear or delete entire cell.  I've seen this out there that deletes the entire row, but I want to delete just the cell with a partial match.

For example, search through and clear or delete the cell data that contains any partial match to 'Print'
There will be a random image name and number in front of the word Print like "19-Test-IMG_5690 :: Print"
Is it possible to have a script search my sheet or range of cells and clear or delete those cells with the partial match?

This was the closest I could find:  That does what I want but only in column B and it doesn't work on partial matches.

```
function clean0() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange('B:B').getDisplayValues();
  var range = [];
  data.forEach(function(e, i){
    if (e[0] == "Print") range.push("B" + (i + 1));
  });
  sheet.getRangeList(range).clearContent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function clearCellsThatContain_Print_() {
  clearCells(/Print/i);
}

function clearCells(searchFor, sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()) {
  if (!searchFor) return;
  const cellsToClear = [];
  sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues()
    .forEach((row, rowIndex) => row
      .forEach((value, columnIndex) => {
        if (value.match(searchFor)) {
          cellsToClear.push(sheet.getRange(rowIndex + 1, columnIndex + 1));
        }
      })
    );
  cellsToClear
    .forEach(cell => cell.clearContent());
}
```

The `searchFor` parameter should be a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). You can also use a normal text string, as long as it does not contain any [characters that require escaping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#writing_a_regular_expression_pattern).

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/), [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: thanks for the response!  i tried your function and it cleared all kinds off stuff it shouldn't have.  sorry but doesn't appear to be working properly for some reason. i will try a few quick edits first..

Comment: you are right i did try to run directly from script editor.  sorry.  soo i don't understand what you mean by call it from another function... i guess i do understand, but i've never done that and don't know how to try....

Comment: Simply run the `clearCellsThatContain_Print_()` function to test it. This structure lets us keep the `clearCells()` a bit more generic, so that you can create additional functions that clear cells using criteria other than "Print" if necessary.

Comment: wait... you just told me in the above comment running directly in the script editor is not what i should do, but now you are telling me to simply run the clearCellsThatContain_Print_() function to test it?  so where do i run it if it is not from the script editor??  i'm confused.  but thanks for the help  ... so i did run from the script editor this time and it did nothing...

Comment: _Do not_ run the `clearCells()` function in the script editor. _Do_ run the `clearCellsThatContain_Print_()` function in the script editor, or through any other means such as a [custom menu item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) or a [button](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets).